# How to set custom notification sound on Skype on Android

Tags: skype, notifications

I believe the question is pretty self explanatory but I'll repeat myself regardless.

Is there a way I can change the notification sound on Skype, on Android, from the default one? With or without the help of a third party program.

I own a rooted device, in case that helps.

Comment: [Nope](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/change-notification-sound-android/td-p/1402750/page/3)

Comment: Some folks likes to copy the APK, remove the app, extract the APK to find the sound files irritating them and replace them with the sound file they want to be played. They then repack the extracted content into an APK, install it and remain happy. Well not happy forever because the method has a huge drawback: their app is never updated again.

Comment: Better than nothing. Thanks for letting me know.